# Django ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico

Tags: python, django, hosting

I am hosting my site in Digital Ocean and it keeps me sending this email.
[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico

Currently I have not taken any domain and surfing through ip. Is this error because of this ?

Also when I try to upload any image it doesnt upload either from client side or admin side.  It sends me 3 4 error messages all related to image..\

Traceback is:

```
Internal Server Error: /img/loading.gif
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/eclinicnepal/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 150, in get_response
response = callback(request, **param_dict)
File "/var/www/html/eclinicnepal/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 105, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/html/eclinicnepal/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 31, in page_not_found
body = template.render(RequestContext(request, {'request_path': request.path}))
File "/var/www/html/eclinicnepal/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 209, in __init__
updates.update(processor(request))
File "/var/www/html/eclinicnepal/eclinicnepal/eclinicnepal/context_processor.py", line 4, in notifications
'unseen_notifications': request.unseen_notifications,
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'unseen_notifications'
```

Like the error last line says there is nothing error in that file.. It looks something like

```
def notifications(request):
"Context processor for adding notifications to the context."
return {
    'unseen_notifications': request.unseen_notifications,
    'seen_notifications': request.seen_notifications
}
```

In my local thats working perfectly without errors.. Whats the error?

And why my image is not uploading ??

Comment: Is it the same error everytime? If so, when do you add the `unseen_notifcations` to the `request`?

Comment: Find out what was causing this? I am also getting an error on favicon access in a context processor but I have no idea how or why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are reporting two issues here. An internal server error for your favicon and the `WSGIRequest` error.

For the favicon, if your static settings aren't correct or if you are using an IP rather than a domain, and if your Apache virtual host configuration isn't correct... you will get errors like these. I have found that going from local to development on a server is not trivial, so I would confirm this first.

For the context processor. I might recommend taking this out and getting it working first, and then adding it back in. Often, troubleshooting like this can reveal other errors that lead to solutions.

I use Digital Ocean for several projects and I have deployed Django projects to this platform using virtual environments on many occasions, so I have seen many errors related to static content and context.

Have a look at this blog post which covers most of the basics when deploying to Digital Ocean:

https://pdxpixel.com/blog/2013/05/13/configuring-dango-on-apache-with-mod_wsgi/

https://pdxpixel.com/blog/2013/05/10/setting-up-django-on-ubuntu-with-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/

The second one deals with the same configuration but using `virtualenv` which I recommend. there is a learning curve, but it's well worth it.